# Store and validate hashed password with salt

Tags: java, hash

I simulate storing password hashes and validate it in login process.

I have a method called `hashPassword(String password)` to get a String password and returns it's hash with adding of salt.

I choose salt an static value and in this example, i choose an identical value for password (`hello123`)

```
public class T1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userDefinedPassword = "hello123";
    String hashedPassToStoreInDB = String.valueOf(hashPassword(userDefinedPassword));
    System.out.println("what stores in DB: " + hashedPassToStoreInDB);
    // store in database

    //Password Verify
    String inputPassword = "hello123";
    String hashedInputPassword = String.valueOf(hashPassword(inputPassword));
    System.out.println("Users hashed password: " + hashedInputPassword);

    if (hashedPassToStoreInDB.equals(hashedInputPassword)) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
}

private static byte[] hashPassword(String password) {
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    byte[] hash = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        salt[i] = (byte) i;
    }
    try {
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        hash = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsale) {
        nsale.printStackTrace();

    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ikse) {
        ikse.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hash;
}
}
```

But the result is:

```
what stores in DB: [B@219c9a58
Users hashed password: [B@305918a5
Incorrect
```

Why this two value is not identical?

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: On a side note: You should handle passwords as char array instead of Strings: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String hashedPassToStoreInDB = String.valueOf(hashPassword(userDefinedPassword));
```

and here:

```
String hashedInputPassword = String.valueOf(hashPassword(inputPassword));
```

You're creating a `String` from the `byte[]` returned from `hashPassword` method, but using the wrong method. Since there's no overload for `byte[]` in `String#valueOf` method, it ends calling [`String#valueOf(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) which will use `Object#toString` internally, and the string representation of an array by itself is meaningless.

Use [`new String(byte[] byteArray)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) instead.

```
String hashedPassToStoreInDB = new String(hashPassword(userDefinedPassword));
//...
String hashedInputPassword = new String(hashPassword(inputPassword));
```

Comment: Yes, `Correct` message appears, but in console appears `���;{O�|�.��="` why?

Comment: @user3808021 because some `byte`s cannot be represented as a proper `char` value in a console or in a text file e.g. `byte` values between 0 and 32.

Comment: well, Is it better to store this hashed password in database in `String` or in `byte` ?

Comment: @user3808021 `String`

Answer (score 0):

You are generating two different instances of a `byte[]` array, whose `String` representation follows the one from `Object.toString`.

Hence the hashes of your two `byte[]`s are different.

Try comparing `Arrays.equals(yourSaltedPassword, yourOtherSaltedPassword)` instead.

For instance:

```
byte[] foo = {1,2};
byte[] bar = {1,2};
System.out.println(foo == bar);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(foo).equals(String.valueOf(bar)));
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(foo, bar));
```

**Output**

```
false
false
true
```

If you need to store your `byte[]`s as `String`s, you can represent them equally (for equal `byte[]`s) with `Arrays.toString(myByteArray)`.

The comparisons between the two equal passwords will then return equal `String`s.

Comment: So, i need to store user hashed password in `byte` in database, not in `String`, Correct?

Comment: @user3808021 no, you have to use [`new String(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) constructor instead of `String#valueOf(byte[])`.

Comment: @user3808021 assuming this is all for test/learning (i.e. real security is out of scope), you can store `Arrays.toString(yourByteArray)`. The comparison will then return equal.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree but that couldn't that cause further issues with encoding in this specific context?

Comment: @Mena you could use `new String(byte[], CharSet)` if needed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know :) Just being picky here.

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled on to the fact that java arrays do not override toString.

Bug why use arrays: You can get a basic salt working by just concatenating strings, then using `hashCode()` on the result:

```
int hash = (password + salt).hashCode();
```